# how to search between comma separated field in linq

Tags: c#, linq

How to search for a value which is comma separated in database through linq. My scenario is user can select Multiple value from listbox and then search those item in comma separated field in database.
I select two items so the value will be 2,3 and database field have values

```
1,2,4,5
1,4,3,6
2,3,4,5
1,4
```

The selected records must be record no 1 because it has 2, record no 2 because it has 3 and record no 3 because it has both and reject record no 4.
What i try is

```
string Commodites = "2,3";
obj.Where(e => Commodites.Contains(e.Id)).Distinct()
```

but it select only those record which have value 2,3 only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For CSV splitting I advise you to use any CSV parser, not simply use `string.Split` method.

```
string[] input = { "1,2,4,5", "1,4,3,6", "2,3,4,5", "1,4" };

var result = input.Where(l => l.Split(',').Any(s => new[] { "2", "3" }.Contains(s)));
```

Comment: @RitchMelton, Read CSV spec. For example, `,` or new line escaping. It works only for simple CSV files.

Comment: Krill Polishxhuk - Right, its a simple tool for when things are simple.